# Unable to launch Swift 5 app with Xcode 11

Tags: launch, xcode11, swift5

I have just updated the Xcode to version 11.0. I have made a new app using the Storyboard with only a View Controller and an entry point. However, nothing happens when I click on the launch button.

Do I have to change some settings or something else?
My product-type is 'Archive'

Comment: You should give more details, eg., the error you get?

Comment: @OnurTuna No error, just nothing happening. Appart from the changes above everything is on the default settings

Comment: It even does not build?

Comment: @OnurTuna It does build, but the Simulator doesn't open

Comment: "My product-type is 'Archive'"  - what does that mean?

Comment: @DavidS. In my products folder (as the project target) I have an Archive File("xxx.a")

Comment: Are you building an app, or a shared library? Apps are not .a files, but shared libraries cannot be launched on a device or simulator.

Comment: that was the problem thanks!